# HttpPlatformHandler HTTP Bad Gateway Error

Tags: iis, httpplatformhandler

I wrote a HttpPlatformHandler exe that works pretty well. I added code to exit the exe if it has been idle for 5 minutes. The exe does exit after 5 minutes but the next client request usually gets a Bad Gateway error. I was expecting that the handler would just start the exe.

The application pool has a timeout feature but if there is a request processing that takes longer than the timeout, it gets killed before completion.

Is there a way for the exe to end itself in a way that the handler can handle?

Comment: "I added code to exit the exe if it has been idle for 5 minutes." Why? HttpPlatformHandler didn't expect that to happen, so any error might happen. Configure application pool idle shutdown instead, and then the handler can shut down the backend application server process(es) for you.

Comment: The exe has single and multi-threaded modes. Sounds like I should always use multi-threaded so that it can respond immediately to new requests even when there is a long running one in progress.

Comment: To prevent the application pool from automatically shutting down, you can set the application pool's idle time to 0.